# Duplicate named argument - how to add more then one child to a body in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Error in line 18:

Error: The argument for the named parameter 'child' was already specified. Try removing one of the named arguments, or correcting one of the names to reference a different named parameter.dart(duplicate_named_argument)

Why body can't have more then one child? 
How to solve that?

```
class mainMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Bar Iland"),

      ),
      body: Center(
        child:
         Image.asset(
                    'assets/Bar_Iland_line.png',
                    height: 200,
                    color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.80),
                  ),
        child:
          Column( 
          children: <Widget>[
            Spacer(flex: 8),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children:[                  
                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),

              ],
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 1),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children:[
                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox.fromSize(
                      size: Size(90, 90), // button width and height
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.orange, // button color
                          child: InkWell(
                            splashColor: Colors.green, // splash color
                            onTap: () {}, // button pressed
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Icon(Icons.call), // icon
                                Text("Call"), // text
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
              ],
            ),
            Spacer(flex: 10),
          ],
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you cannot have two `child`s - you need `children` but it cannot be used in `Center` widget - you have to use either `Row` or `Column` widgets - more https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-multiple-widgets-vertically-and-horizontally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pskink mentioned, you can't have two children in a body.

Use

```
Scaffold(
  body: Column( // or Row or Wrap 
     children: [
       Child1(),
       Child2(),
     ]
  )
)
```